# SEO effects of linking to subdomain

Tags: seo, subdomain, links

I have http://hollywoodnose.com as a main site. Then I have http://forum.hollywoodnose.com as the subdomain.

I'm cautious to link to the subdomain from the main site. I did this before and droped 50% of traffic from the main site.  Also, Google Webmaster Tools showed over 3000 incoming links from Hollywood Nose to the subdomain / forum.  I'm assuming Google frowned on this and saw it as spam or something of that nature.

All I would want is link to the subdomain in the top nav bar of the main site. Is this safe? Will I get an overabundance of incoming links resulting in an SEO drop? Does anyone have any experience in this matter? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subdomains are seen as part of the same website as domain.com so this won't have any effect on your SEO.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see how just linking to a subdomain could cause negative SEO effects. Many websites use subdomains for various things, like forums, support, news, etc.